# Comparing value from a webpage and value from a database table in spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper

My question is quite different... 
I am having a web page which gets some values from the user and saving into a table called xyz. And I am having  a table called zyx which has some similar columns like in the table xyz.

Now i need to compare the similar columns values in both the tables and need to display some data in my web page based on the comparison..

I have no idea on this.  Please give a clear idea in this.

Thanks in advance

and sorry for my Bad english

Please refer the web page [image]

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/effortloading/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody  EffortLoadingBean submitEffortloading(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginbean") Loginbean loginbean, Model model, 
            @ModelAttribute EffortLoadingBean effortloading, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpServletRequest request) {

        logger.debug("<<<<< EffortLoading Start >>>>>>");
        System.out.println(":: effortBean  :: "+effortloading);
        String elXml = "";
        loadCombo(loginbean, model);
        int monthPos=0;
        try{
            //      ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();
            effortloading.setOPPORTUNITY_DATE(request.getParameter("OPPORTUNITY_DATE").toString());

            elXml="<EffortLoad>";
            for(int rad=0;rad<effortloading.getPHASE().length;rad++){
                System.out.println(effortloading.getMonthData().getMonthData()[rad]);
                elXml+="<Data>"+
                        "<DocId>"+effortloading.getDOC_NO()+"</DocId>"+
                        "<Phase>"+effortloading.getPHASE()[rad]+"</Phase>"+
                        "<RsrcGrade>"+effortloading.getRESOURCE_BY_GRADE()[rad]+"</RsrcGrade>"+
                        "<RsrcName>"+effortloading.getRESOUCE_NAME_PER_ROLE()[rad]+"</RsrcName>"+
                        "<Deployment>"+effortloading.getDEPLOYMENT()[rad]+"</Deployment>"+
                        "<Geo>"+effortloading.getGEO_PER_PRACTICE()[rad]+"</Geo>"+
                        "<RsrcGrpCat>"+effortloading.getRESOURCE_GROUP_CATEGORY()[rad]+"</RsrcGrpCat>"+
                        "<Month>";
                String monthData="";
                for(int mnthInd=0;mnthInd<effortloading.getDURATION();mnthInd++){
                    //monthData=effortloading.getMonthData().getMonthData()[monthPos];
                    if(mnthInd==0){
                        monthData=effortloading.getMonthData().getMonthData()[monthPos];
                    }else{
                        monthData+="~"+effortloading.getMonthData().getMonthData()[monthPos];
                    }

                    monthPos++;
                }

                elXml+=monthData+"</Month>"+
                        "</Data>";
            }
            elXml+="</EffortLoad>";
            System.out.println("elXml---->"+elXml);



            int effortAdded = effortLoadingService.add(effortloading, loginbean,elXml);
            //      HashMap<Object,HashMap<Object,Object>> effortHM = new HashMap<Object,HashMap<Object,Object>>();
            //      effortHM = ajaxService.next(obj,effortloading);

            if (effortAdded > 0) {
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("css", "success");
                effortloading.setPersistResponse("SUCCESS");
                //          redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "effortloading.countryForm.msg.success");
                logger.debug("End");
                //          return "redirect:/welcome";
                return effortloading;
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("css", "danger");
                //          model.addAttribute("msg", "country.countryForm.msg.failed");
                logger.debug("End");
                effortloading.setPersistResponse("FAILURE");
                return effortloading;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            effortloading.setPersistResponse("FAILURE");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return effortloading;
        }

        /*String docNo = effortBean.getDoc_no();
        String oppNo = effortBean.getOPPORTUNITY_NO();
        System.out.println("docNo -->"+docNo +"oppNo --> "+oppNo);


        modelView.addObject("effortBean", effortBean);
        return "EffortLoding";*/

    }
```

Impl:

```
@Override
    public int travelLoadSave(EffortLoadingBean effortLoadingBean, Loginbean loginbean,String tpXml) {
        String dtlTPQry="";
        int effortTRN=0;
        try{
            dtlTPQry="UPDATE TRANS_ELOADING_DTL SET TRAVEL_DTL="+"XMLType('"+tpXml+"'), MODIFIED_BY='"+loginbean.getUserId()+"', MODIFIED_DATE=SYSDATE"+ 
                    " WHERE DOCID ='"+effortLoadingBean.getPrimaryKey()+"'";
            System.out.println(" :: << dtlTPQry >> ::"+dtlTPQry);
            effortTRN = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(dtlTPQry,new MapSqlParameterSource());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return effortTRN;
    }
```

The above data is storing in a table. Now I need to compare the values with another table in database

Comment: please add some code you have tried and hasn't worked otherwise it's not possible to troubleshoot

Comment: where do you need help..On Spring MVC?.Please specify where exactly u need help

Comment: Guys please help.. I have surfed through the internet but i don't find any solution